# How to use WSASetService to advertise bluetooth service using WSAQUERYSET structure on Windows devices

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth

I read from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/bluetooth-and-wsasetservice that there are two ways to submit a service to local SDP server:

- The application can have the system advertise a simple Bluetooth SDP service record, constructed from standard members in the WSAQUERYSET structure.
- The application can have the system advertise their own Bluetooth SDP record by passing a BTH_SET_SERVICE structure in the lpBlob member of the WSAQUERYSET structure. This is a more complex approach.

For me, the first is preferred, but all code examples I can find now use the second. I think it probably involves setting information about the service, such as address, port, service uuid in WSAQUERYSET members:

```
    // Service Information
    int port = 4;
    BTH_ADDR address = xxx;
    GUID serviceUuid = {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx};
    char* serviceName = "xxx";
    //....

    // Putting service information into WSAQUERYSET
    WSAQUERYSET Service;
    memset( &Service, 0, sizeof( Service ) );
    Service.dwSize      = sizeof( Service );
    Service.dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
    //Service.xxx         = xxx
    //...
    
    if ( WSASetService( &Service, RNRSERVICE_REGISTER, 0 ) == SOCKET_ERROR ) {
        return WSAGetLastError();
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
```

Currently, I'm guessing how to set these attributes, but somehow I could not successfully advertise a service that could be detected. I really hope to have some workable code examples.

Comment: Depending on your requirements it might be better to use case 1. For example, if your service is just SSP (Serial Port Profile) then you do not need any additionl protocols information to be added to the SDP record so using only UUID is enough. However if your service is something like OBEX based profile then you have to add additional protocol information into SDP and should use case 2. Any way, your code snippet looks OK and should register the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first you need not hardcode `port = 4;` but use `bind` for get dynamic free port and `getsockname` for get port number. for instance (without error check)

```
SOCKADDR_BTH asi = { AF_BTH, 0, {}, BT_PORT_ANY };
SOCKET s = WSASocket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM, 
    0, 0, WSA_FLAG_NO_HANDLE_INHERIT|WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
bind(s, (PSOCKADDR)&asi, sizeof(asi));
int len = sizeof(asi);
getsockname(s, (PSOCKADDR)&asi, &len);
```

then you need call WSASetService, as described in [*Bluetooth and WSAQUERYSET for Set Service*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/bluetooth-and-wsaqueryset-for-set-service). here described all params, used in `WSAQUERYSET`. only one exception - *lpszServiceInstanceName* described as

> *Optional, but recommended.*

but if not use it - we got *An invalid argument was supplied*. so this is mandatory parameter.

```
ULONG BthRegisterService(LPCGUID lpServiceClassId, PCWSTR ServiceName, PSOCKADDR_BTH asi)
{
    CSADDR_INFO csa = { 
        { (PSOCKADDR)asi, sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH) }, {}, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM 
    };

    WSAQUERYSET wqs = { sizeof(wqs) };
    wqs.lpszServiceInstanceName = const_cast<PWSTR>(ServiceName);
    wqs.lpServiceClassId = const_cast<PGUID>(lpServiceClassId);
    wqs.dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
    wqs.dwNumberOfCsAddrs = 1;
    wqs.lpcsaBuffer = &csa;

    return WSASetService(&wqs, RNRSERVICE_REGISTER, 0) ? WSAGetLastError() : NOERROR;
}
```

cons of this way - we can not got back `HANDLE` of record which we register, for late call `WSASetService` with `RNRSERVICE_DELETE` - for this need use `BLOB` which point to `BTH_SET_SERVICE`. for this we need format by self raw SDP record stream.

so call `BthRegisterService`  we can in whis way:

```
struct __declspec(uuid("00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff")) MyServiceClass;
BthRegisterService(&__uuidof(MyServiceClass), L"*", &asi);
```

however, if we can format SDP record, we also can direct use [`IOCTL_BTH_SDP_SUBMIT_RECORD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/bthioctl/ni-bthioctl-ioctl_bth_sdp_submit_record) for register and later [`IOCTL_BTH_SDP_REMOVE_RECORD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/bthioctl/ni-bthioctl-ioctl_bth_sdp_remove_record) for deregister

for open bluetooth device need use [`CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_device_interface_listw) with `GUID_BTHPORT_DEVICE_INTERFACE`

SDP record formated by NspSetService look like

```
UCHAR SdpRecordTmplt[] = {
    // [//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    0x35, 0x33,                                                                                                 //
    //
    // UINT16:SDP_ATTRIB_CLASS_ID_LIST                                                                          //
    0x09, 0x00, 0x01,                                                                                           //
    //      [/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  //
    0x35, 0x11,                                                                                             //  //
    // UUID128:{guid}                                                                                       //  //
    0x1c, 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff,   //  //
    //      ]/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  //
    //
    // UINT16:SDP_ATTRIB_PROTOCOL_DESCRIPTOR_LIST                                                               //
    0x09, 0x00, 0x04,                                                                                           //
    //      [/////////////////////////////////                                                                  //
    0x35, 0x0f,                             //                                                                  //
    // (L2CAP, PSM=PSM_RFCOMM)              //                                                                  //
    //          [/////////////////////////  //                                                                  //
    0x35, 0x06,                         //  //                                                                  //
    // UUID16:L2CAP_PROTOCOL_UUID16     //  //                                                                  //
    0x19, 0x01, 0x00,                   //  //                                                                  //
    // UINT16:PSM_RFCOMM                //  //                                                                  //
    0x09, 0x00, 0x03,                   //  //                                                                  //
    //          ]/////////////////////////  //                                                                  //
    // (RFCOMM, CN=Port)                    //                                                                  //
    //          [/////////////////////////  //                                                                  //
    0x35, 0x05,                         //  //                                                                  //
    // UUID16:RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID16    //  //                                                                  //
    0x19, 0x00, 0x03,                   //  //                                                                  //
    // UINT8:CN                         //  //                                                                  //
    0x08, 0x**,                         //  //                                                                  //
    //          ]/////////////////////////  //                                                                  //
    //      ]/////////////////////////////////                                                                  //
    //
    // UINT16:SDP_ATTRIB_SERVICE_NAME                                                                           //
    0x09, 0x01, 0x00,                                                                                           //
    // STR:4 "ABCD"                                                                                             //
    0x25, 0x04, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44                                                                          //
    // ]//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
};
```

here only UUID128 (*ServiceClassId*), rfcomm port number and name is changed

---

even if we format raw SDP record himself - windows add to it 2 attributes:

```
(UINT16:ServiceRecordHandle) (UINT32:xxxxx)
```

and

```
(UINT16:BrowseGroupList) [ (UUID16:PublicBrowseRoot) ]
```

so for example if we pass next sdp record:

```
[ // 30
    (UINT16:ServiceClassIDList)
    [ // 11
        (UUID128:00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff)
    ]
    (UINT16:ProtocolDescriptorList)
    [ // C
        [ // 3
            (UUID16:L2CAP_PROTOCOL_UUID16)
        ]
        [ // 5
            (UUID16:PSM_RFCOMM)
            (UINT8:CN=Port)
        ]
    ]
    (UINT16:ServiceName)
    ("ABCD")
]
```

windows convert it (extend) to

```
[ // 40
    (UINT16:ServiceRecordHandle) (UINT32:10001)
    (UINT16:ServiceClassIDList)
    [ // 11
        (UUID128:00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff)
    ]
    (UINT16:ProtocolDescriptorList)
    [ // C
        [ // 3
            (UUID16:L2CAP_PROTOCOL_UUID16)
        ]
        [ // 5
            (UUID16:PSM_RFCOMM)
            (UINT8:CN=Port)
        ]
    ]
    (UINT16:BrowseGroupList)
    [ // 3
        (UUID16:PublicBrowseRoot)
    ]
    (UINT16:ServiceName)
    ("ABCD")
]
```

or in raw bytes - the record:

```
UCHAR sdp[] = {
     0x35 ,0x30 ,0x09 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0x35 ,0x11 ,0x1c
    ,0x00 ,0x11 ,0x22 ,0x33 ,0x44 ,0x55 ,0x66 ,0x77
    ,0x88 ,0x99 ,0xaa ,0xbb ,0xcc ,0xdd ,0xee ,0xff
    ,0x09 ,0x00 ,0x04 ,0x35 ,0x0c ,0x35 ,0x03 ,0x19
    ,0x01 ,0x00 ,0x35 ,0x05 ,0x19 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0x08
    ,0x04 ,0x09 ,0x01 ,0x00 ,0x25 ,0x04 ,0x41 ,0x42
    ,0x43 ,0x44
};
```

converted to

```
UCHAR sdp_final[] = {
     0x35 ,0x40 ,0x09 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0a ,0x00 ,0x01
    ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0x09 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0x35 ,0x11 ,0x1c
    ,0x00 ,0x11 ,0x22 ,0x33 ,0x44 ,0x55 ,0x66 ,0x77
    ,0x88 ,0x99 ,0xaa ,0xbb ,0xcc ,0xdd ,0xee ,0xff
    ,0x09 ,0x00 ,0x04 ,0x35 ,0x0c ,0x35 ,0x03 ,0x19
    ,0x01 ,0x00 ,0x35 ,0x05 ,0x19 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0x08
    ,0x04 ,0x09 ,0x00 ,0x05 ,0x35 ,0x03 ,0x19 ,0x10
    ,0x02 ,0x09 ,0x01 ,0x00 ,0x25 ,0x04 ,0x41 ,0x42
    ,0x43 ,0x44
};
```

Comment: Small correction: 1. Service name must be UTF8 encoded. 2. If BLOB is used the lpszServiceInstanceName  can be NULL.

Comment: @RdMm Addition: 3. You missed ServiceRecordHandle in your SDP record. 4. You missed BrowseGroupList (PublicBrowseGroup) in your SDP record (without this some device may not see the record). 5. In ProtocolDescriptorList you missed "Data element sequence" header that includes PSM and RFCOMM data. Without this PSM and RFCOMM headers looks like two separate protocols for client (but must be as sequence of single data frame.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko 1 - *must be UTF8 encoded* in raw sdp record  - this is direct documented uder link. 2 - *If lpBlob is provided to the WSASetService function, all other members of the WSAQUERYSET structure except dwSize and dwNameSpace are ignored.* - so of course can be 0 in this case - simply not view sense copy paste here all from msdn

Comment: @MikePetrichenko - 3 *You missed ServiceRecordHandle in your SDP record* i not understand this point.. we only can receiver this handle back, after api end. or may be you  mean something another. about - i missed.. - i simply take record which format `NspSetServiceFromQuerySet`, so if i something missed - windows dll missed this too. however all this work ok when connect 2 windows devices how minimum ( i personally use raw sdp and ioct direct)

Comment: really record formated by `NspSetServiceFromQuerySet` not containing `UINT16:PSM_RFCOMM `  ( *0x09, 0x00, 0x03,* )this i add by self here (this is only example), all another copy-paste from what `NspSetServiceFromQuerySet` format

Comment: tipical windows formated sdp - https://i.imgur.com/NND8FBL.png

Comment: Did I already reffered you to Bluetooth core specification? If not, please take a look on it first. It does not matter what windows does (I saw lot of china Android devices that have incorrect SDPs). The important thing is what Bluetooth specification says. Yes, 2 PCs running Windows will work. But if you try to use other device it may not work.Especially because you did not put your SDP into Publis Browsable Group.

Comment: If you recommend something to someone it must be completly correct and full. That is why I post only the comments because fulkl answer take a lot of time and needs to explaing a lot of things.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko - if we will use `WSASetService ` without `BTH_SET_SERVICE` - widows format such record template. simply as is. record i paste only as example. question was about how create *simple Bluetooth SDP service record, constructed from standard members in the WSAQUERYSET structure.* - here not need by self format sdp. wshbth do this for you. you can look under debugger - what is formated

Comment: Exactly. That is why there is a way to submit your own SDP as raw. And that must be correct. If someone made mistake abd formated SDP incorrectly why shoul doy ucopy thaa mistake? A long time ago I spent weeks to understand why Symbian can't connect to Windows PC.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko how format full correct sdp record another question. here i also agree with you. i am only windows developer and look at first - what windows do. i test this only in connect 2 windows based device between self

Comment: That makes sense. However Bluetooth developed by SIG and only SIG specification can be correct to make it working on/with any Bluetooth enabled devices. However, SIG also made some mistake by not publishing detailed description of SDP records in Profiles specification. The most important thing such as Public Browsable Group can be found only in Bluetooth Core Spec that waste your time for searching. That is why I reffered to Bluetooth Core Spec, not to specific profiles spec. BlueZ (Linux) always builds correct SDP and its better to take a look on its implementation than on Windows one.

Comment: Also about handle. By some reason on some Windows versions (in fact I do not remember on which one) if you did not put the Record Handle chunk in the SDP raw data it will not be fullfilled by Windows (even it returns correct handle to the application). So it is always good idea to have one there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240429/discussion-between-rbmm-and-mike-petrichenko).

Comment: @MikePetrichenko - *3. You missed ServiceRecordHandle in your SDP record. 4. You missed BrowseGroupList (PublicBrowseGroup) in your SDP record (without this some device may not see the record).* - how i checked now - both this attributes auto added in kernel to submited record. as result not need add this by self. update answer

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I think it's ok not to get the handle to remove the record later, since it's mentioned in the document that services advertised through WSASetService will be automacially removed when the process terminates.